# Simple issue that is hard to resolve - order of data in a report - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Any help would be appreciated please.

I have set up a simple report that shows date, timeslot and reason for visit. However the timeslot displays in order that the order was processed and I get for example:

```
Date            Timeslot        Reason
24/11/14        1300-1800       Repair TV
24/11/14        0800 - 1200     Repair TV
```

So even though on 24/11/14 we have a morning appointment booked, it appears on the report after the afternoon one, because the office handled the call requesting a PM booking first.

So what I would like is for the timeslot to show to earlier times first:

```
Date            Timeslot        Reason
24/11/14        0800 - 1200     Repair TV
24/11/14        1300 - 1800     Repair TV
```

This would normally be simple but data for timeslot comes from a field which contains several items of data (fields!businessnamevalue), where several pices of information are gathered, eg timeslot, customer's name, reason for visit etc. This data is organised in the report as:

=switch(fields!businessname.value = "TIME", "timeslot", fields!businessname.value = "CustName", "Customer's Name")

So my issue is, can the field (fields!businessname.value) be 'split up' in any way other than by using switch, so I can sort my report so the timeslot shows morning appointments before pm appointments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a switch statement in the expression/function related to the sort.

Under 'sorting options' add a new sort line item (or modify the existing item) by clicking the expression button to the right (Fx)

Then Modify the sort expression similar to this:

> =fields!businessname.value = "TIME", Format(CDate("timeslot"),"hh:mm tt").

I have not tested the expression but that should give you an idea. You could pick a hint from [Controlling Sorting in SSRS Based Upon a Database Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541477/controlling-sorting-in-ssrs-based-upon-a-database-text-field)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to get back to me. I tried the switch statement as suggested, but this led to my column headings being called 'xxx' 'yyy'. Basically I have a field I mentioned above, when put into a report, splits into 3 values: time, reason and address. I'm really keen to somehow separate this time element of the string. Do you / does anyone know of a way of pulling a value from a string field (maybe via a calculated field?) and then sorting from that?  Many thanks.